# Not able to get background image to be responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am new to CSS and am trying to edit a Wordpress site. It has a background image that may be inserted with Javascript.  The background image I can get to be responsive when working in Dev Tools but I'm not able to make it responsive once I add CSS to this Wordpress site. I'm not sure that I'm using the right Selector, or if there's anything I can do in CSS to change the image to being responsive. Maybe my CSS is wrong. I know that inline styles take precedence over other type of styles so I tried using the !Important keyword, but still not able to transfer what I see in Dev Tools to this Wordpress site. The height of the image was set to 650px, so I changed that to "auto" and that made things look right in Dev Tools, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it happen on this site.  Any help would be appreciated.
[how it looks in dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvwj0.png)
[my CSS code that I added in Wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ca18c.png)

Comment: Please do not send images of your code. Post your literal code on your question.

Comment: `object-fit:cover;` --> https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp

Comment: I find that the library [backstretch](https://www.jquery-backstretch.com/) is petty good at handling advanced responsive use cases. Might be worth your investigation.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I looked at the object-fit:cover; and that may be what i need to use with a value of 'contain'.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use `background-size:cover;` or `background-size:100% auto;` in css

Comment: I will try that. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

All I can say is that I had such problem a couple of times, however, I had to solved the issue in different ways all every time.

One time was the theme that it had a preset setting to the background image in the CSS file.
Solution: Get to the CSS configuration file of the theme and change it there; then save it and fixed.

Another time it was a CSS conflict between my CSS and the CSS from an plugin.
Solution: Deleted all the plugins, set the CSS commands and add back all the plugins. Issue fixed.

The last time it was an error on my theme installation.
Solution: reinstall theme then set CSS rule, and fixed.

Good luck. I hope it helped.

Comment: That makes sense Scoaband. I think it is somewhere in the CSS theme file. And, yes there may be a plugin conflict looking at all these plugins and the fact that many need updating.  Thank you.